# Understanding an equality with open balls

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

In order to understand a proof I want to know why the following is true:

Let X be a banach space and $x\in X$ with $x\in B(x_0,r)$ (open ball around $x_0$ with radius $r$), then $\frac{r}{2}x-x_0 \in B(x_0,r)$

That should be quite easy but I still can't understand it.

So I hope someone can explain why it is true. Maybe with a good explanation, but I would like to see a proof involving $d(\frac{r}{2}-x_0,x_0)\leq....\leq r$

Thanks!

**Edit:** The assumption also says that $||x||=1$

Comment: say on the real line $x_0=3$, $r=2$, $x=1.2$, then $\dfrac r 2 x-x_0= -1.8\not\in B(x_0,r)$. On the other hand if you were trying to prove $x_0-\dfrac r2 x \in B(x_0,r)$, in general, use $d(x_0-\dfrac r2 x,x_0)=||x_0-\dfrac r2 x -x_0||=||\dfrac r2 x||$ ?

Comment: yeah, but how do you bound $||x||$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot something ||x||=1, see above

Comment: Then it follows easily since $\frac{r}{2} < r $ and $|| \alpha x || = \alpha ||x|| $ fo $\alpha > 0 $

Comment: I know that, but I actually can't write down why its like that

Comment: see Mirko's comment

Comment: Does it hold that $d(\frac{r}{2}-x_0,x_0)=d(x_0-\frac{r}{2},x_0)$?, hmmm..I guess no..

Answer (score 1):

it is not true, say on the real line take $x_0=3$, $r=2$, $x=1.2$, then $\dfrac r 2 x-x_0= -1.8\not\in B(x_0,r)$.

Hmm, edit, now the assumption says $||x||=1$.

On the real line take $x_0=2.5$, $r=2$, $x=1$, then $\dfrac r 2 x-x_0= -1.5\not\in B(x_0,r)$.

Comment: $||x||=1$, sorry I forgot that..

Comment: $||x||=1$ ... it doesn't help. Try to figure out what typo they made in the book, and what makes sense in that proof, whatever it is, perhaps they put the subscript $_0$ in the wrong place, or something ?

Comment: Yea.. right now I am looking again..Its from our lecture. The proof of banach-steinhaus theorem

Comment: If you intersect an open ball with a dense set, the intersection would be non-empty, so there exists an element that belongs to the open ball ... just a wild guess, might make sense in the context of the proof of [Banach-Steinhaus theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle)